# Programatically visualise your html in different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, rendering

Is there a way to programatically visualise/render the current state of your html (or DOM) in different browsers, without having to install those different browsers on your machine.

Comment: You can try headless browsers with selenium or any other similar automation framework.

Comment: Thanks @Asutosh, but I was referring to something that will capture the current state of the DOM and render it in a specified browser

Comment: Try BrowserStack service

Comment: @charlietfl that will run the whole test in the specified browser rather than capture the current state of the test and render that page in a different browser. Also looking for non-cloud solutions

Comment: Well actually it runs in numerous browsers simultaneously and gives you visualization of all. Isn't that what you asked?

Comment: @charlietfl I know what you mean, I've edited the description with the phrase "current state". So not looking for something that will run the whole test in parallel on different browsers. Only want to run the test in one browser, but when I get to the end, I want to capture a screenshot of that point, in different browsers

Comment: So you want non-cloud but you also don't want to install the different browsers on your machine? You would need the browser installed somewhere in order to view how it rendered your html.